# uses vim as an ide

Tags: vim, ide

I want plugins for vim so that I can use it as a C language IDE. I used to use qtcreator and I really appreciate his auto-completion (really perfect), but after trying for several months vim I really begins to fail in love with his working method.

So if anyone have used qtcreator and vim, it will be nice if he advise me which plugins or options that helps me use vim as an IDE.

**ps:** I know there is the fakevim in qtcreator mode (which allows you to move around like vim) but the problem is when I activate this feature instant auto-completion in qtcreator disappears (and even display prototype, because what I really like in qtcreator is that you dice step function it shows you in her gray prototype so that you may know which parameter use with the function).

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can configure FakeVim plugin in recent-enough Qt Creator so it passes key presses in insert mode to Qt Creator's code completion engine. Click on Tools/Options menu item, select FakeVim tab and set "Pass keys in insert mode" checkbox -- alternatively you can just use `:set passkeys` or `:set pk` in FakeVim.

Answer (score 0):

A quick goggle for

> site:vim.org ide complete function arguments

The first hit is c.vim: http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=213

There is also good discussion further down about Source Explorer, Taglist and NERD Tree plugins.